# Syntax to use deja-dup over network with ssh

Tags: networking, 20.04, 22.04, backup, deja-dup

Currently I use deja-dup to backup to a external ssd. The SSD is mounted under `UbuntuBackup` with folder `mini`. I am about to put this computer into semi-retirement. Then I would like to back up my new computer using this same one. I understand that to enable that, I would then choose `Network Server` from the `Storage Location` dropdown menu and then enter a value for `Network Location`. I am unsure of the syntax for that. As an alternative example, using fish with ssh from Midnight Commander the "URL" would be something like `/sh://tim@oldcomputer/UbuntuBackup/mini`. What would be an example of a protocal to enable this new backup procedure? NOTE: I have passwordless ssh set up.